# WebBrowser control wont display content from a object source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

i get some HTML returned from an external source and set to a simple string. However when i set the DocumentText param of the control nothing gets changed. This seems to be a common issue, and ive tried the results from previous posts to no avail.

Also the .show() method doesnt seem to pop the window up? In the code below it creates a new window, sets some params and tried to open the browser.

```
private void createWindow(String text)
    {
        if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Nothing has been returned, possible MBean Failure");
        Window a = new Window();
        a.Title = "Output";
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        rtb.FontSize = 12;
        rtb.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#639FBE"));
        rtb.IsReadOnly = true;
        rtb.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        rtb.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Auto;
        rtb.Margin = new Thickness(15);
        Grid myGrid = new Grid();
        a.Content = myGrid;
        myGrid.Children.Add(rtb);
        rtb.AppendText(text);   
        a.Height = myGrid.Height;
        a.Width = myGrid.Width;

        if (text == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Nothing has been returned,    possible Failure");
        browser.Navigate("abount:blank");
        HtmlDocument doc = browser.Document;
        browser.Document.OpenNew(true);
        doc.Write("<HTML>" + text + "</HTML>");
        browser.DocumentText = doc.ToString();


        browser.Show();



      //  a.ShowDialog();


    }
```

Comment: Does text have `<body>` tags?  What is the value of doc.ToString()?

Comment: Added them, seems to have helped strangely? DocutmentText is now being displayed, but the .Show() method is not popping up the browser control. 

Is there anyway i can tie it to the Window control? and have it display with that?

Comment: Why is that strange?  The body tags aren't optional.  A WebBrowser can be added to a form in the normal way.  It isn't itself a form, you need to add it to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your HTML looks malformed.  `<body>` tags aren't optional
2. A WebBrowser is a control that needs to be added to a form -- it is not itself a form.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do document writing in [Navigated event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`NavigateToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx)? That seems to be far easier than doing anything with the document.

*(If you have tried things that failed you should mention what they were and why they did not work by the way)*

Comment: That seems to be what i need but i dont have access to it? Using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

Comment: @User10: Why is your question tagged WPF if you use Winforms?

Comment: I am using WPF but using this winforms control, i wasnt aware of any other i could use? If there is please enlighten me. Its simply to display some HTML code, such as tables populated with data.

Comment: @User10: There is this [WPF WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) to which the aforementioned method belongs.